# How to create Cassandra columns having whitespace without double quotes?

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

I am creating cassandra table, where some column can have white spaces like "Marks Obtained in %"

I can create table like below which works

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (Time text ,"Marks Obtained in %" text ,PRIMARY KEY (Time));
```

The issue is now for all my retrieve query, I have to supply column name inside double quotes else it will not work.

ex:

```
select "Marks Obtained in %" from test1
```

The column name itself becomes "Marks Obtained in %" with double quotes and not <Marks Obtained in %> without double quotes.

Since table creation is via python program, I need to maintain uniformity, while creating all the columns.

Is there any way in cassandra to make column names with white spaces, I saw in SQL something like below

```
CREATE TABLE IDE_Dump
(
   Name VARCHAR(255),
   [Head Name] VARCHAR(255),
   [Parent Account] VARCHAR(255) 
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to do specify a column name with spaces without enclosing them in quotes.

As a workaround, swap the spaces with underscores (`_`) like `column_name`. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but in my scenario, we  should not alter the name of column, but thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative approach is to use a column with the [supported character limits](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/definitions.html#identifiers) and during the selection, use `SELECT marks_in_perct AS "Marks Obtained in %" from keyspace_name.table_name WHERE ...;` to achieve this.

Comment: Can I do similar while creating the table ?

Comment: Unfortunately, nope. Table creation step has to have the exact name of the column. And... if you need to retain mixed cases / space, you would end up providing the double-quotes and that column name will have that and when you access you need to provide double-quotes